# How do I load an image uploaded to S3 in my website?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm sure this question has been debated a lot. But I searched for some hours and I don't seem to find a solution to this. Most guides are old or I can't make them work when I try.

I'm working in a Nodejs + React application and I'm using S3 to store images. I want the React app to load the image, so I need to provide it a URL in the future. I have worked with S3 in the past (and RoR) and I remember I used to create a temporary URL and it was refreshed from time to time.

Tutorials I found say I have to create a URL like this:

`https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<image>`

So, not a temporary URL, and it doesn't work either way. I get a "Access Denied" xml in return. I even have granted permissions in this file (I selected "Make it public") but it doenst seem to work.

So how should I load this image in React? How do I retrieve it from the service? I'm using the official SDK.

Comment: Step 1: Upload an image in the S3 Management Console. Select the image and view the link it shows. Use that link. If everything works, then incorporate that knowledge into your app. If it doesn't work, we can help you debug it and you know it's not your app that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

upload your image as public in s3 and check that the image is given public rights by copying and pasting URL returned by s3 in web browser and if image renders then use the image tag in below mentioned way

Insert your image url of S3 bucket in src

`<img src = "https://yourS3Url/image.jpg" alt = "HTML IMAGE"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

Add these policy to the S3 bucket

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal": "*",
           "Action": [
               "s3:GetObject"
           ],
           "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"
       }
   ]
}
```

Then add these cors config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <MaxAgeSeconds>9000</MaxAgeSeconds>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

upload files and then you can access file

```
<img src = "https://yourS3Url/image.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What is needed is a 'Pre-signed URL'. Making buckets public isn't recommended.

In terms of NodeJS is something like:

```
s3Client.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
   Bucket: bucket,
   Key: key,
   Expires: timeInSeconds
});
```